# Webpack 4, postcss-loader and autoprefixer plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm getting quite frustrated trying to get autoprefixer working.

Here is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const config = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: "css-loader", options: {} },
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: {} },
                    // {
                    //  loader: "postcss-loader",
                    //  options: {
                    //      ident: "postcss",
                    //      plugins: (loader) => [
                    //          require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: ['defaults']})
                    //      ]
                    //  }
                    // },
                    { loader: "sass-loader", options: {} }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.mp3$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "main.css"
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my **postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')()
  ]
}
```

Currently my **package.json** is holding my browserslist options

As you can see I've tried using the webpack file to hold my config settings for postcss-loader and I've also tried creating a separate config file.

I've tried moving the browserslist but I don't think that's the issue bc I run `npx browserslist` and I can see a list of browsers that were selected.

My `postcss-loader` declaration in my webpack config comes after `css-loader` and before `sass-loader`

I also receive no errors in my console when I run webpack so not sure what is happening but could really use some help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not working but `{ browsers: ['defaults']}`

Try:

```
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]_[hash:base64:6]',
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')({
                        'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
                    })],
                }
            },
        ]
    }
```

or

```
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')({
            'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: I tried using different values for the browsers list, but it's still not working. I don't think the browsers list is the problem because I run `npx browserslist` and I can see which browsers should be affected.

Comment: I tried to edit my previous comment, but your answer actually does work! I know I tried different values for the browsers option but for some reason it is working this morning... it's possible I had spelling errors I suppose. The only value that doesn't seem to work is the `defaults` option. Thanks for posting!

Comment: This also worked for me after trying everything else +1

Answer (score 16):

The big picture here is that you are actually missing the [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) package on your environment, so to fix the problem you have two solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
npm install --save-dev postcss-loader autoprefixer
```

Now inside your **postcss.config.js** file you can add something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')({
      'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
    })
  ]
};
```

**Solution 2 (recommended)**

This one comes from [PostCSS Loader documentation](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#autoprefixing), and since you are using this package perhaps this is the recommended way to go.

> **postcss-preset-env** includes **autoprefixer**, so adding it separately is
>   not necessary if you already use the preset.

As you can see in order to get Autoprefixer you just need to install [PostCSS Preset Env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env).

```
npm install --save-dev postcss-loader postcss-preset-env
```

Now get rid of your **postcss.config.js** file and move that configuration into your **webpack.config.js** to make it look to something like this:

```
...
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      { loader: "css-loader", options: {} },
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: [
            require('autoprefixer')({
              'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
            }),
          ]
        }
      },
      { loader: "sass-loader", options: {} }
    ]
  }
]
...
```

I hope this helps, it also took me a long time to figure it out too ;)

Comment: Looks like you still declare plugins with preset available.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, you need to specify the browser-list. 
But instead of adding this to your `webpack.config` and to the `postcss-config` you can add the following code simply to the `package.json` after the dependencies. Worked for me.

```
"browserslist": [
  "> 1%",
  "last 2 versions"
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Try edit like this

webpack.config.js:

```
{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader", "css-loader", 'postcss-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'
            ]
        },
```

postcss.config.js:

```
require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 10 versions']}),
```

Comment: When change the browsers versions from `defaults` to any other option things appear to be working