# autoprefixer with webpack 4 doesn't add prefix or work at all

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

I've tried so many ways to include autoprifixer in my app, here is what I've

"webpack": "^4.35.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
"css-loader": "^2.1.1",

```
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 6 version",
        "not dead"
    ],
```

```
config = {
entry: {
... scss/js files
}
module: {
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

]
},

plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '/app/css/build/[name].css'
        }),
        new ManifestPlugin(),
    ]

}
```

Links to other questions that i've tried

[webpack with less and postcss autoprefixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846209/webpack-with-less-and-postcss-autoprefixer)
[Webpack 4, postcss-loader and autoprefixer plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782806/webpack-4-postcss-loader-and-autoprefixer-plugin)
[Webpack + SASS + Autoprefixer are not generating the CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275032/webpack-sass-autoprefixer-are-not-generating-the-css-file)